# Python can't recognize file in Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, io

I've got the following small program that runs fine on Windows 7:

```
import csv
filename = raw_input('Enter input file name: ')
outfile = raw_input('Enter output file name: ')
with open(filename) as f, open(outfile,'w') as f2:
    writer = csv.writer(f2, delimiter = '\n')
    for line in f:
        x, y = line.split() 
        writer.writerow([y]*int(x))
```

However, running the same code on a Mac, when we give `input.txt` for the input file, we get an `"Error 2: input.txt, no such file or directory"` error.

So far we've confirmed that we're running in the same working directory as the input file. We've tried entering the complete path (with and without quotation marks) instead of just the file name. We've also tried explicitly specifying the encoding - utf8 - even though I'm not sure that should be necessary. We just keep getting the same "no such file or directory" error. Again, this runs fine under windows. Any ideas?

UPDATE: OK, invisible leading whitespace in the file name turned out to be the problem. It runs fine once we get rid of that (although it's a mystery why OSX puts it there in the first place...)

Comment: Have you tried looking at `os.getcwd()` and `os.listdir()` outputs?

Comment: If memory serves, *nix (which OSX is) will report no such file or directory in scenarios where the user is attempting to access a given resource to which the user does not have the correct permissions.  Do you run your program under a user that has read/write permissions to the directory where your program lives, and that if the in/out files you are trying to use exist, the user has permissions to those as well?

Comment: Using Python 2.7.2 on Mac OS X 10.8.4, I get past the `with` line and the code gives me the error: `Enter output file name: output.txt
Traceback (most recent call last): File "csv.py", line 1, in <module>
 import csv
  File "/Users/jleffler/soq/csv.py", line 5, in <module>
    writer = csv.writer(f2, delimiter = '\n')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'writer'`.  My `input.txt` file contains one line `1,2,3,4`; the file `output.txt` has been created (but it's empty, of course). I suggest you copy the script and input to a different directory (`/tmp` for example) and try again.

Comment: (Maybe I should add: and I'm working from a terminal window.  If you're using some sort of IDE, then all bets are off as far as I'm concerned — I'm a luddite w.r.t IDEs.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Did you create a script called `csv.py` to test this?  Because that's going to break the `import` statement in the script; instead of importing the actual csv module from the core libraries, its going to try to import itself, and yes, it doesn't have an attribute `writer`.

Comment: @SilasRay: Yes, I did call it `csv.py`; not thinking...under-caffeinated...

Comment: Sometimes this can be the solution: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989554/why-cant-i-find-a-file-in-python-2-7-on-mac-os-x-2-7-5/20989555#20989555