# Why do I get a "No such file or directory" error on macOS?

Tags: python, macos, file-io, directory

Using the following code:

```
fileName = 'Data\\all_earthquakes.csv'
with open(fileName, 'rb') as csv_file:
    attrHeaderRow = csv_file.readline().strip()
```

I get the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Data\\all_earthquakes.csv'
```

It works perfectly fine on my Windows 7 machine.

Comment: I am wondering why you posted this question.

Comment: Because I had this problem and figured it out midway through posting the question. Decided to answer it, in case anyone hadn't run into this problem. I never had and I have used Python for 5 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows and Mac OS X use different characters to separate elements in paths. Windows uses the backslash, Mac OS X (and Linux/UNIX) uses the forward slash. Python takes care of this for you: use `os.path.join` to build paths using the correct separator for the current operating system or use `os.sep` if you need the actual character that is used for path separation.

```
import os
import sys

fileName = os.path.join('Data', 'all_earthquakes.csv')
print('Directory separator on your platform ({}): {}'.format(sys.platform, os.sep))
```

Note that Windows generally accepts the forward slash as path separator as well when using Windows APIs - it's just CMD.EXE that does not accept them. That's why on Windows, `os.altsep` is set to the forward slash (and people just use the forward slash in all paths, even on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code as follows:

```
fileName = 'Data/all_earthquakes.csv'
with open(fileName, 'rb') as csv_file:
    attrHeaderRow = csv_file.readline().strip()
```

Mac OSX uses a different file structure, which leads to the difference in forward or backward slashes in the directory name.

If you want to do a check for this, use the following code:

```
from sys import platform as _platform
if _platform == "linux" or _platform == "linux2":
# linux
elif _platform == "darwin":
# OS X
elif _platform == "win32":
# Windows...
elif _platform == "cygwin":
#cygwin install
```

More information can be found here:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html